# What are the criteria for Community Wiki posts?

Tags: discussion

I just asked [my first question on german.stackexchange.com](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/german-learning-apps-for-google-android) and I was a little bit surprised to note that it had been marked as Community Wiki.

What are the criteria here for Community Wiki questions? How do they differ from Stack Overflow?

Comment: I changed it to community wiki because it was a big-list type of question with no objective criteria for finding the right answer, which makes it more of a poll-type question. I think that that implies CW, but can't find the relevant meta.SO post.

Comment: @Tim N - This seems like a viable answer to the question. Can you post it as an actual answer, please?

Comment: @Robert: My comment only explained the example, not the (more general) question. I've posted a similar answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions should be community wiki if they are asking for big lists without objective criteria for finding the right answer. Such questions encourage poll-style voting. There should be no difference between community wiki here and on StackOverflow.

Note that, as Dori says, polls are still discouraged.

Comment: My question wasn't intended as a big list as such, and it's certainly not a poll, since it's asking for some factual information with a definite objective answer for a specific purpose. I was a little unclear as to whether this kind of question is acceptable on DE.SE though -- I found one example of a similar question in the site definition voted as "on topic" yet another similar example voted as "off topic." Thanks for clarifying though: +1 and accepted.